# 2D array grouping 1's in C

Tags: arrays, c, grouping

2D array of 1s and 0s. How to label every group of 1s with a unique number?
I’m stuck on this problem for a while now. 1s can be grouped vertically, horizontally and diagonally. How can you go about solving this? For example,

```
0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
```

Should be transformed to

```
0 0 x x 0
0 x x 0 0
0 0 0 0 y
0 0 0 y 0
```

`x`, `y` can be any unique numbers.

Appreciate it.
Here is what I have so far for iterative: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuVTc.png
But the result is a bit off because it only checks for immediate adjacent 1's: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2rj6.png
Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please do not post code and other text as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

1. Scan 2D array sequentially, row by row, column by column
2. If 1 found, use variation of the flood fill algorithm, which moves in 8 directions instead of 4, from that starting point (see normal 4-direction algorithm at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), since you have diagonal example with "y", each time using new filler number.
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until no more ones left.